# Pig HCatLoader java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.type.HiveVarchar

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

I am having below external hive table which I will be using later for processing.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive_test_table(
  cmp_dte DATE,
  my_ind CHAR(1),
  typ_desc VARCHAR(40),
  def_typ_desc VARCHAR(60),
  tt_ind CHAR(1),
  nn_nm VARCHAR(80),
  xzs_desc VARCHAR(60),
  pqa_desc VARCHAR(40),
  aac_cnt INT,
  pqdd_cnt INT,
  nnc_cnt INT,
  ors_amt DECIMAL(18, 2),
  rddd_amt DECIMAL(18, 2),
  btdff_id BIGINT,
  fil_tss STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY( chnldd VARCHAR(40))
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION '/test/locationn'
;
```

To process the data I want to read it in pig using below code,

```
existing_data = LOAD 'hive_test_table' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader() ;
```

getting below error,

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias existing_gold_paid_search_data. Backend error : Error converting read value to tuple
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:872)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:774)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:541)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 6018: Error converting read value to tuple
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatBaseLoader.getNext(HCatBaseLoader.java:76)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader.getNext(HCatLoader.java:58)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader.nextKeyValue(PigRecordReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.type.HiveVarchar
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.PigHCatUtil.extractPigObject(PigHCatUtil.java:413)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.PigHCatUtil.transformToTuple(PigHCatUtil.java:456)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.PigHCatUtil.transformToTuple(PigHCatUtil.java:374)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatBaseLoader.getNext(HCatBaseLoader.java:64)
```

Can anyone please help, how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: What version of Hive is this?

Comment: @franklinsijo, Hive version is 0.13.

Comment: Try adding this property `hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false` in `hive-site.xml`, if this does not solve upgrade Hive to a newer version. This was a bug in earlier versions of Hive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known issue for the hive version 0.13

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11054